# Reloading a div makes it all black

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reload

I have this div which should be updated from the database with some data.
I want to reload this div here every 5 sec:

```html
<div class="account-left">
  <div class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0">
    <div class="section" id="myscroll">
      <!--<h1 style="color:black;">{{hais}}</h1>-->

      <div style="text-align: center; background: #eee;">
        <span ng-show="tasklist.options.no_tasks" ng-bind-html="tasklist.options.no_tasks.message"></span>
      </div>
      <ul style="border:1px solid #ddd;border-top:0;">

        <li ng-class="{active:task.task_id == activeValue, 'cursor-pointer':1 }" id="{{'taskLists_' + task.task_id}}" ng-model="task_title_list" ng-repeat="task in tasklist.data| filter:{task_status:'!draft'} | filter: taskFilterCriteria as results" ng-class="{active : task.task_id == activeValue, 'cursor-pointer':1 }"
        ng-click="mytaskfn(task.task_id, $index + 1, task.taskEscTitle, 'browse-task')" ng-attr-title="{{task.task_is_social_task=='yes' ? 'Donate' : ''}}">
          <div class="browse-tasks-sidebar-col-1">
            <img ng-src="{{task.user.user_avatar ? task.user._links.avatar.href : 'themes/customer/images/dummy-user-img.png'}}" class="img-circle" alt="avatar">
          </div>
          <div class="browse-tasks-sidebar-col-2">
            <a>{{task.task_title}}</a>

            <p class="side-col1-1"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
              {{task.task_type=='online' ? 'online' : task.task_location}}
            </p>
            <p class="side-col1-2" translate translate-values="{comment_count:task.taskComments[0].commentCount, offers_count:task.taskBids[0].bidCount}">{{'comment_offer_count'}}</p>

            <span ng-show="task.task_is_social_task == 'yes'" class="pull-right">
                                                <i class="fa fa-money"  style="color:slategrey"></i>
                                            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="browse-tasks-sidebar-col-3">
            <span class="pull-right">
                                                <!-- if assigned, show assigned offer price. Otherwise show initial poster offer price -->
                                                {{task.task_status == 'draft'|| task.task_status=='posted' || task.task_status=='waiting_paypal_approval' ||
                                                (task.task_status=='cancelled' && !task.assignees.assignees_bid_price) ? currencySymbol + task.task_total_cost : currencySymbol + task.assignees.assignees_bid_price}}</span>
            <br>

            <!-- <button type="button" class="small-btn">EARN</button>-->
            <!-- <a ui-sref="home.browse-tasks.details({taskid:task.task_id, task_title:task.task_title})" class="small-btn pull-right"   ng-click="mytaskfn(task.task_id, $index + 1)" translate>{{'VIEW'}}</a> -->
            <a class="small-btn pull-right" ng-class="{disable:task.task_status != 'posted' && task.task_status != 'waiting_paypal_approval'}">
              <span translate="
{{
    task.task_status=='posted' || task.task_status=='waiting_paypal_approval' ? 'VIEW':
    (
       ( task.task_status=='assigned' || task.task_status=='poster_paid' || task.task_status=='started' ||
         task.task_status=='completed'
       ) ? 'Assigned' :
            ( task.task_status=='cancelled' ? 'Cancelled' :
                ( task.task_status=='expired' ? 'Expired' : 'Completed' )
            )
    )
}}
                                                      "></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- <button class="signup-btn comnt-btn task-alllocate-green loadmore" ng-click="loadMore()">Load more</button> -->
      <a class="loadmore" ng-hide="1" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="loadMore(loadvalue, activeTab)">Load more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

I did this but after 5 sec it becomes all black .

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function() {
    //  window.location.reload(1);
    $('.account-left').load('browse-tasks.html');
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

Is there a way to reload it in the right way?
Thanks!

Comment: This can be done, but why would you do that. please explain the scenario, so I can help better

Comment: I edited the question @ArunKarnawat

Comment: If it become all blank then `browse-tasks.html` is returning nothing

Comment: and if you want to refresh content of `account-left` every 5 second use `setInterval(function() {}, 5000);` instead of `setTimeout(function() {}, 5000);`

Comment: @ArunKarnawat The same result

Comment: try accessing `browse-tasks.html` directly and check if it is printing anything or not.

Comment: if you are not working on local, can you share url

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible.

```
var w = window.open(url, "test");
w.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to update database entries on a button click. but from your point of view what does reload or update another page means ?